# I cannot hide navigation dropdown when click outside

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that I cannot remove class when I click outside the dropdown menu. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/nguyenchinhhiep/pen/oNvdzOB

```
var getNavItem = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
getNavItem.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var siblings = getSiblings(this);
    siblings.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('active');
    })
    this.classList.toggle('active');

// Remove when click outside
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if(event.target.tagName == 'BODY') {
        this.classList.remove('active');
      }

   })
  });
});

// Get Siblings
var getSiblings = function (elem) {
    var siblings = [];
    var sibling = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
    for (; sibling; sibling = sibling.nextSibling) {
        if (sibling.nodeType !== 1 || sibling === elem) continue;
        siblings.push(sibling);
    }
    return siblings;
};
var elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');
```

Comment: Why are you binding the body click event inside of a loop? You are adding tons of events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove class **'active'** on outside click:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].contains(e.target)) {
      // Clicked on dropdown
    } else {
      // Clicked outside the dropdown
      els[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
});
```

```js
// Navigation mobile
var getNavbar = document.querySelector('nav');
var getNavbarToggler = document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');
var getNavbarNav = document.querySelector('.navbar-nav');

getNavbarToggler.addEventListener('click', toggleNavbar);

function toggleNavbar() {
  getNavbarToggler.classList.toggle('active');
  getNavbarNav.classList.toggle('active');
}

// Dropdown Menu

var getNavItem = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
getNavItem.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var siblings = getSiblings(this);
    siblings.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('active');
    })
    this.classList.toggle('active');

  });


});

// Get Siblings
var getSiblings = function(elem) {
  var siblings = [];
  var sibling = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
  for (; sibling; sibling = sibling.nextSibling) {
    if (sibling.nodeType !== 1 || sibling === elem) continue;
    siblings.push(sibling);
  }
  return siblings;
};
var elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');

// code for hiding dropdown

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].contains(e.target)) {
      // Clicked on dropdown
    } else {
      // Clicked outside the dropdown
      els[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* Global Styles */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Navigation */

nav {
  background: #333;
  transition: all ease .4s;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-link,
.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.dropdown-item:hover {
  background: #111;
}

.nav-link.active,
.nav-link.active:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item.active .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.nav-link i {
  transition: all ease .4s;
}

.nav-item.active i {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow-icon {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.sticky-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all ease .4s;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    background: #444;
  }
  .dropdown-item {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: block;
    transition: all ease .3s;
  }
  .navbar-toggler.active {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  .navbar-toggler.active .navbar-toggler-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    transition: all ease .3s;
  }
  .navbar-toggler.active .navbar-toggler-icon:first-child {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  .navbar-toggler.active .navbar-toggler-icon:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggler.active .navbar-toggler-icon:last-child {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
    transition: all ease .4s;
  }
  .navbar-nav.active {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .nav-link {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Navigation</a>
    <div class="navbar-toggler">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="m1">
        <a class="nav-link">Dropdown 1
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link">Dropdown 2
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: FYI, for this to work on touch devices you will also need to listen to the `touchend` event since non-interactive elements (e.g. links, buttons, inputs) don’t trigger click events. You can test for support with `"ontouchend" in window`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will cause every click in the `main`-div to close the dropdown:

```
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    getNavItem.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.remove('active')
    })
})
```

Just put it below your code from above and remove this

```
// Remove when click outside
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName == 'BODY') {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
})
```

from your code.